# What app can help me selecting music from within a folder of tracks?

Tags: android

I am looking for an android app whith which I can select music during e.g. driving a car. With the app I want to be able to select a folder containing music files (e.g. mp3 files). The app is to play the music  one after another. But in addition I want to see large buttons easy to press (because I am driving) to delete music file I do not want, skip to the next track, or pause. That way I can remove tracks from a set of music I do not like, and keep only the ones I like.

Does such an app exist? If not, I will create it on my own...

Answer (score 1):

VLC for Android might meet some of your requirements. It allows per-folder playing, playlists and so on. It has homescreen widgets that might be able to provide large buttons for changing the track and pausing.